# Take screenshot at specified coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a Windows Forms application, how do I take a "screenshot" of certain coordinates?

In the picture below, you see a Window and inside that window is a little gray box, somewhere near the center.

[image]

Where every I might place that box, how can I take a "screenshot" of it (including whatever content is inside it) programmatically?

Comment: You kinda forget to add the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simple way

Simple, use `Graphics.CopyFromScreen`

```
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Graphics graph;

graph.CopyFromScreen(X, Y, 0, 0, Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

Now you can use `bitmap`, that contains a source copy of the area.

### Hacky way

```
SendKeys.Send("%{PRTSC}"); //Alt + PrtSc to screenshot just the active window.
Bitmap clipboardImage = Clipboard.GetImage(); //Get image from the clipboard
//Here you crop the image using Bitmap.Clone();
//Be happy and question yourself why you are doing this way.
```