# How to take a screenshot at specific coordinates of the user's screen and save it as example.jpeg c#?

Tags: c#, image, graphics, bitmap, save

I want to take a screenshot with upper left corner P, width w, and height h, and then save it.

I tried this. [Take screenshot at specified coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774611/take-screenshot-at-specified-coordinates). Doesn't work, or I don't know how to make it work.

Then I tried saving the clipboard, didn't work either.

```
SendKeys.SendWait("%{PRTSC}"); 
Bitmap bp = new Bitmap(Clipboard.GetImage());
bp.Save(@"C:\Users\hasht\spamImages\work.png", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I also tried

```
private Bitmap bitmap;
private Graphics graph;
... 
graph.CopyFromScreen(new Point(1600, 0), new Point(1920, 0), new Size(320, 300));
Bitmap bp = new Bitmap(320, 300, graph);
bp.Save(@"C:\Users\hasht\spamImages\work.png", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

but then graphics was null, since I never created it. Turns out you cannot create a graphics object. How would I take a screenshot with upper left corner P, width w, and height h, and then save it?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
    Bitmap printscreen = new Bitmap(150, 150);

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(printscreen as Image);

    graphics.CopyFromScreen(Point1, Point2, 0, 0, printscreen.Size);
    printscreen.Save(PATH_FILENAME, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Works fine on [keylogger project](https://github.com/lagripe/Keylogger)

Answer (score 0):

I put everything into a function.

```
/// <summary>
/// Takes a screenshot of the specified section of the screen.
/// </summary>
public void Screenshot(string filename, ImageFormat imageFormat, int width, int height, int sourceX, int sourceY, int destX, int destY)
{
    using (var bm = new Bitmap(width, height))
    {
        using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
        {
            gr.CopyFromScreen(sourceX, sourceY, destX, destY, bm.Size);
            bm.Save(filename, imageFormat);
        }
    }
}
```

An an example, to take a 500x500 screenshot starting at the upper left corner of the screen:

```
Screenshot(@"c:\temp\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg, 500, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

It may require these imports at the top of your c# class:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

The graphics object in your code was null because it was never initialized.  The "var gr  = Graphics.FromImage(bm);" line is what initializes it in my example (providing a Bitmap which it will then write to).

I'm using a "using" statements with the Bitmap and the Graphics object because the Dispose method needs to be called on them when they are done (which the using statement will do automatically even if there is an exception).

Comment: It is the x and y coordinates of the point at the upper-left corner of the destination rectangle.  Here's a link to some of the documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: An error occur
************** Exception Text **************
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
   at WindowsFormsApp1.Form1.Screenshot(String filename, ImageFormat imageFormat, Int32 width, Int32 height, Int32 sourceX, Int32 sourceY, Int32 destX, Int32 destY) in C:\Users\hasht\source\repos\WindowsFormsApp1\WindowsFormsApp1\Form1.cs:line 118

Comment: When that error happens on "Save" it can be caused by permissions, it can be caused if the file is still locked if it were saved twice but not released.  It can be caused if the directory location where you place the file doesn't exist, it can be caused if the path has illegal characters.